# Update default value of form element with AJAX

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I have an email field on node add form , I want to check if this email exist fill the city field in the same node form , then my code is :

```
function custom_code_form_car_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  $form["field_user_email"]['und'][0]['email']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'user_ajax_check',
      'wrapper' => 'field-user-city-add-more-wrapper',
      'effect' => 'fade',
  );
}


function user_ajax_check($form,$form_state){
    // load the user then
    $form["field_user_city"]['und'][0]['value']["#default_value"] ="foo";
    return $form["field_user_city"];
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Can you provide a more thorough explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value must be set in the `hook_form_alter`, not in the callback of ajax :

```
function custom_code_form_car_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  $form["field_user_email"]['und'][0]['email']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'user_ajax_check',
      'wrapper' => 'field-user-city-add-more-wrapper',
      'effect' => 'fade',
  );

  if(!empty($form_state['values']['field_user_email']){
       $form["field_user_city"]['und'][0]['value']["#default_value"] = "foo";
  }
}


function user_ajax_check($form,$form_state){
    // load the user then       
    return $form["field_user_city"];
}
```